# UNDO statement releases available buffer within class instance

Tags: database, class, openedge, progress-4gl, undo

I've added the test codes down below.

`TestClass` has `BUFFER` variable inside itself which is available after the execution of it's `CONSTRUCTOR`.
Everything works fine until the code executes any `UNDO` or (`UNDO, THROW...`). After this the class instance is otherwise intact, except that the `BUFFER` variable is now `NOT AVAILABLE`.

Is there any way to prevent `Progress` from doing this `RELEASE`?

In the below test codes, the second `iValue = oTestClass:Value.` will throw error because the `BUFFER` is `UNAVAILABLE`.

I'm using Progress 11.7.5.

**test.p:**

```
DEF VAR oTestClass AS CLASS TestClass NO-UNDO.
DEF VAR iValue     AS INT NO-UNDO.

DO TRANSACTION:
    oTestClass = TestService:Singleton:Find().
    iValue= oTestClass:Value.
    UNDO.
END.

DO TRANSACTION:
    oTestClass = TestService:Singleton:Find().
    iValue = oTestClass:Value.
    UNDO.
END.
```

**TestClassService.cls:**

```
BLOCK-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW.
CLASS TestService:
    
    DEF PUBLIC STATIC PROPERTY Singleton AS CLASS TestService NO-UNDO
        GET:
            IF TestService:Singleton = ? THEN TestService:Singleton = NEW TestService().
            RETURN TestService:Singleton.
        END.
        PROTECTED SET.
    
    DEF PRIVATE VAR oTestClass AS CLASS TestClass NO-UNDO.
    
    CONSTRUCTOR PROTECTED TestService(): END.
    
    METHOD PUBLIC CLASS TestClass Find():
        IF oTestClass = ? THEN DO:
            oTestClass = NEW TestClass(TO-ROWID("0x000000000017c201")).
        END.
        RETURN oTestClass.
    END.
END.
```

**TestClass.cls:**

```
BLOCK-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW.
CLASS TestClass:
    DEF PRIVATE BUFFER MyTable_This FOR MyTable.
    DEF PUBLIC PROPERTY Value AS INT NO-UNDO
        GET:
            RETURN MyTable_This.Value.
        END.
    
    CONSTRUCTOR PUBLIC TestClass(i_rROWID AS ROWID):
        FIND FIRST MyTable_This WHERE ROWID(MyTable_This) = i_rROWID NO-LOCK.
    END.
END.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute your example on [ABL Dojo](https://abldojo.services.progress.com/?shareId=6491886cd172aa40d044e1ec).

Since a database table is not `no-undo`, any `undo` statement will undo anything done with it, including the `find` that brought the `buffer` into scope.

A buffer on a `no-undo` temp-table does not have this "problem".

Comment: I accepted this as the answer. I ended up adding code for each property where it checks if the `BUFFER` is not `AVAILABLE`, and queries it again if needed. I don't know if dynamic `buffer`s could solve this?

Comment: No, see https://abldojo.services.progress.com/?shareId=6492ed8cd172aa40d044e1ed